# In which order do CSS stylesheets override?

Tags: css, overriding, stylesheet

In an HTML header, I've got this:

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

`styles.css` is my page-specific sheet. `master.css` is a sheet I use on each of my projects to override browser defaults. Which of these stylesheets takes priority?
Example: first sheet contains specific

```
body { margin:10px; }
```

And associated borders, but the second contains my resets of

```
html, body:not(input="button") {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

In essence, does the cascading element of CSS work the same in terms of stylesheet references as it does in typical CSS functions? Meaning that the last line is the one displayed?

Comment: I just now realized this would be better suited for Webmasters. Would there be a better place to post this?

Comment: Right here is good.

Comment: `body:not(input="button")` is not a valid selector by the way. You probably meant to split it into `body, input:not([type="button"])`.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't believe I've seen such syntax before. I'm still new, but those double brackets are foreign to me.

Comment: those brackets are for attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

@topic: probably you want to switch the order of the stylesheets: Your general `master.css` should load first, then it's way easier to overrule the master-styles in your `styles.css`.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The rules for CSS rule cascading are complex -- rather than trying to paraphrase them badly, I'll simply refer you to the spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

In short: more specific rules override more general ones. Specificity is defined based on how many IDs, classes, and element names are involved, as well as whether the `!important` declaration was used. When multiple rules of the same "specificity level" exist, whichever one appears last wins.

Comment: Then there's no specific rule as to in what order stylesheets load? I understand how CSS displays in terms of specificity, but then I'll assume my master sheet will load unless overridden.

Comment: I *believe* that stylesheets are treated as if they're loaded in the order that they're linked in the HTML (even if they actually load out of order), but I'm not certain.

Comment: Something I read earlier suggested the opposite, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Actually, `!important` participates directly in the cascade, and has nothing to do with specificity. Specificity is related to selectors, whereas `!important` is used with property declarations. (So you're right in saying that the rules are complex! ;)

Comment: So do stylesheets load the same way as elements, the last taking precedence if they are of the same specificity?

Comment: @iananananan: Basically, the browser never sees CSS in terms of individual stylesheets. If there are multiple stylesheets, they are all treated as if they were one giant stylesheet, and rules are evaluated accordingly.

Comment: @BoltClock, see document.styleSheets. The browser definitely keeps each the stylesheet separate.

Comment: @user34660 BoltClock's comment is from the perspective of CSS styling. You're correct that the stylesheets are kept separate in the DOM, but that separation doesn't affect how those styles get applied to anything.

Comment: Thank you for "When multiple rules of the same "specificity level" exist, whichever one appears last wins"! This was the piece of information that I needed.

Answer (score 37):

The most specific style is applied:

```
div#foo {
  color: blue; /* This one is applied to <div id="foo"></div> */
}

div {
  color: red;
}
```

If all of the selectors have the same specificity, then the most recent decleration is used:

```
div {
  color: red;
}

div {
  color: blue; /* This one is applied to <div id="foo"></div> */
}
```

In your case, `body:not([input="button"])` is more specific so its styles are used.

Comment: See my comment on the question regarding that last selector.

Comment: The specificity rule make things harder when we need to override un-editable stylesheet!

Answer (score 27):

Order does matter. The last declared value of multiple occurrence will be taken. Please see the same one I worked out: http://jsfiddle.net/Wtk67/

```
<div class="test">Hello World!!</div>


<style>
    .test{
        color:blue;
    }

    .test{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

If you interchange the order of `.test{}`, then you can see the HTML takes value of the last one declared in CSS

Comment: So you should add the most specific CSS last.

Answer (score 22):

The last loading CSS is THE MASTER, which will override all css with same css settings

Example:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
</head>
```

reset.css

```
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

master.css

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The output for the h1 tag will be font-size: 30px;

Comment: Hi. In my case the first defined `.css` is loaded last. Are they applied in order they are loaded or in order they are defined?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Lets try to simplify the cascading rule with an example. The rules goes more specific to general.

1. Applies rule of the ID's one first (over class and/or elements
   regardless of the order)
2. Applies classes over elements regardless of order
3. If no class or id, applies the generic ones
4. Applies the last style in the order (declaration order based on file load order) for the same group/level.

Here is the css and html code;

```
<style>
    h2{
        color:darkblue;
    }
    #important{
        color:darkgreen;
    }
    .headline {
        color:red;
    }
    article {
        color:black;
        font-style:italic;
    }
    aside h2 {
        font-style:italic;
        color:darkorange;
    }
    article h2 {
        font-style: normal;
        color: purple;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the css style

```
<body>
<section>
    <div>
        <h2>Houston Chronicle News</h2>
        <article>
            <h2 class="headline" id="important">Latest Developments in your city</h2>
            <aside>
                <h2>Houston Local Advertisement Section</h2>
            </aside>
        </article>
    </div>

    <p>Next section</p>
</section>
```

Here is the result. No matter the order of style files or the style declaration, `id="important"` applies at the end (note the `class="deadline"` declared last but does not take any effect).

The `<article>` element contains `<aside>` element, however last declared style will take effect, in this case `article h2 { .. }`  on third h2 element.

Here is the result on IE11: (Not enough rights to post image)DarkBlue: Houston Chronicle News, DarkGreen: Latest Developments in your city, Purple: Houston Local Advertisement Section, Black: Next section

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It depends on both load order and the specificity of the actual rules applied to each style. Given the context of your question you want to load your general reset first, then the page specific. Then if youre still not seeing the intended effect you need to look into the specificity of the selectors involved as others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use classes as much as possible. Avoid ID selectors (#) anyway. When you write selectors with just single classes, the CSS inheritance is way more easy follow.

Update: Read more about CSS specificity in this article: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: This is a great article about CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

I suspect from your question that you have duplicate selections, a master set, that goes for all pages, and a more specific set that you wish to override the master values for each individual page.  If that is the case, then your order is correct.  The Master is loaded first and the rules in subsequent file will take precedence (if they are identical or have the same weight).  There is a highly recommended description of all rules at this website http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ When I started with front end development, this page cleared up so many questions.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: Apr 2020, according to @LeeC's comment, this is not longer the case

Yes, it works the same as if they were in one sheet, however:

Load Order Matters!

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

In the above code, there is no guarantee that `master.css` will load after `styles.css`. Therefore, if `master.css` is loaded quickly, and `styles.css` takes a while, `styles.css` will become the second stylesheet, and any rules of the same specificity from `master.css` will be overwritten.

Best to put all your rules into one sheet (and minify) before deploying.

Comment: Consider the case for alternate _nearly identifcal_ style sheets loaded from the <head> section of a page, one containing conditional _media_ attributes to load a styleheet specific to smartphones and tablets. In this case, the logic specified in _media_ must be strictly exclusive for each stylesheet if the load order is indeterminate.

Comment: @n_i_c_k Your answer is incorrect.  The order of _declaration_ is what matters, not the _load_ order.  I just tested this with Fiddler, by halting the download of `master.css`, and letting `styles.css` load fully.  Then, I let `master.css` load.  The "overlapping" style from `master.css` still applied--and the rendering was blocked until `master.css` loaded and was parsed.  *Note*: I tried `rel=preload` on `master.css' (no halting) and that apparently alters its _declaration_ order by hoisting it above `styles.css`.

Comment: Thanks @LeeC, I know at the time of writing my answer was correct, but I'll take your word for it that it's been fixed now and edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ***cascade*** that defines the precedence of declarations. I can recommend the official specification; this part of it is well-readable.

**https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascading**

The following have an effect on the sorting, in descending order of priority.

1. A combination of **origin,** and **importance:**

   1. `Transition` declarations
   2. User agent’s declarations marked with `!important`
   3. User’s declarations marked with `!important`
   4. Page author’s declarations marked with `!important`

      1. Definitions on the element with `style` attribute
      2. Document-wide definitions
   5. `Animation` declarations
   6. Page author’s declarations

      1. Definitions on the element with `style` attribute
      2. Document-wide definitions
   7. User’s declarations
   8. User agent’s declarations
2. If two declarations have the same origin and importance, the [**specifity,**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) meaning how clearly the element is defined, comes into play, calculating a scoring.

   - 100 points for every identifier (`#x34y`)
   - 10 points for every class (`.level`)
   - 1 point for every element type (`li`)
   - 1 point for every pseudo-element (`:hover`) excluding `:not`

   For example, the selector `main li + .red.red:not(:active) p > *` has a specifity of 24.
3. The **order of appearance** only plays a role if two definitions have the same origin, importance and specificity. Later definitions precede earlier definitions in the document (including imports).

Answer (score 0):

I believe when executing the code, it is read top to bottom, meaning the last CSS link would be override similar styles in any style sheets above it.

For example, if you created two style sheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
```

and in both of these, you set the body background-color to two different colors - the color of the body in style2.css would take priority.

You could avoid the styling priority issue by using `!IMPORTANT` inside the class style you would like to take priority, or possibly re-arranging your `<link>` order.