# CSS media queries selectively not working

Tags: css, antd, antd-mobile

I'm trying to style a page, the desktop is working perfectly fine, my problem is the mobile view. The mobile view is working on selected components, like background image is working perfectly.

I want to give this card a width of `300px;` on mobile view, but it's not picking, but when I put height of `700px` or anything it works. As you can see on the screenshot, the mobile styling is cancelled meaning it's not being applied.

[image: Mobile view, the card width is too large for the screen, I need it to be 300px]

Here's my CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 h3 {
font-size: 1.2em;
 }

.ant-card {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.Background {
background-image: url(./images/mob.jpg);
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
}

}

 .ant-card {
   margin: auto;
   width: 400px;
    }
```

Anyone seeing something I'm not seeing?

Comment: Your `@media` statement should be after the **ant-card** one, so it won't be overridden.

Comment: you can find the response there [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459062/in-which-order-do-css-stylesheets-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459062/in-which-order-do-css-stylesheets-override)

Comment: Thank you @QuentinVeron it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is simply the order in the CSS file dictating the preference.
So declare your "default" style *before* a media selector query with the same level of specificity. E.g:

```
 .ant-card {
   margin: auto;
   width: 400px;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   h3 {
     font-size: 1.2em;
   }

  .ant-card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .Background {
    background-image: url(./images/mob.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me.

Comment: @LindaKadz Great! Glad to hear it.  If you could please mark the answer as accepted, it really helps the community (and me :) of course).