Bootstrap - Can't overwrite class values
I am trying to overwrite color values in the navigation bar and just can't get it to work. I must be doing something wrong. I defined the classes active and inactive to change colors in the navigation.
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="author" content="WDieter Reuther">
  <meta name="description" content="Testing CSS">


<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">


  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Customization -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">


  </head>

  <body>

<header class="navbar-light navbar-sticky header-static">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #27a800;">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link inactive" href="/page1.html">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link inactive" href="/page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>`

custom.css
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
Custome Styling
*/

 .inactive {color: #ffffff !important; }
 .active {color: #333333 !important; }

I was expecting that my custom css colors would overwrite the bootstrap colors. They don't.
I also would be happy if I could change the bootstrap colors, i.e. --bs-navbar-active-color via css.

Have you used your browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being picked up?

Does this answer your question? Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap

This CSS code lets you customize the colors of links in a Bootstrap navbar. Just set the --bs-nav-link-color to change the default link color, and --bs-navbar-active-color to change the color of active links.
.nav-link {
    --bs-nav-link-color: yellow;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
    --bs-navbar-active-color: red;
}



.nav-link {
    --bs-nav-link-color: yellow;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
    --bs-navbar-active-color: red;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="author" content="WDieter Reuther">
      <meta name="description" content="Testing CSS">
      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header class="navbar-light navbar-sticky header-static">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #27a800;">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/page1.html">Page 1</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/page2.html">Page 2</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </header>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
`




This works like a charm! I did have some cache issues initially, but now it is fine. Thank you so much!

just change order of the style import in the hierarchy (custom.css should be applied first and thus will have higher priority)
  <!-- Customization -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

Edit:
What I wrote above is nonsense. You will need to use a more specific CSS selector:


@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
Custome Styling
*/

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active {
  color: #333333;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.inactive {
  color: #ffffff;
}




I think this is the wrong way round see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459062/in-which-order-do-css-stylesheets-override

Isn't it the other way around? The stylesheet that comes later in the sequence takes priority.

Yes, true, my mistake. I apologize.
If you want to overwrite Bootstrap colors, you will need to use a more specific CSS selector:
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active
or
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.inactive
It also depends on what styles are applied to the element and how specific the selector is. I recommend avoiding the use of !important
